# I can print the result in the console but it doesn't work in my js

Tags: javascript

I can print this in the console. [This is the link](https://www.scrumpoker-online.org/en/room/459911/scrum-poker)

```
document.getElementsByClassName('flip-card-back')[0].innerHTML
```

But when I'm doing the same in the JS (in an extension in firefox) this doesn't work.

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('flip-card-back')[0].innerHTML)

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var eles = document.getElementsByClassName('flip-card-back')[0].innerHTML;
    console.log(eles);
})
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I've tried using MutationObserver.

According to the documentation of MutationOberserver I've tried using it.

```
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
console.log('test');
const targetNode = document.getElementsByClassName('flip-card-back');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
    for(const mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
        }
        else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
console.log('test2')
// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
// Later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
console.log('test3')
```

Test and test2 is printed but test3 is never printed, seems like it keep observing but never getting anything.

Comment: `load` means the HTML has finished loading. If the `.flip-card-back` element is added in with JavaScript on its own load listener your JavaScript may execute too soon.

Comment: @PeterKrebs And how could I wait for the page complete? Notice that this script execute when I do click in the extension, but it still not work even if I click after some minutes

Comment: You could use a `MutationObserver` to wait for the element to be added.

Comment: @Barmar Updated with `MutationObserver`

Comment: The target node needs to be a container that already exists, so you can detect when the new node is added to it. Also, the argument to `observe()` needs to be a single node, not a `NodeList`.

Comment: @Barmar I'm kinda new in js, how could I know what could be the correct "container"? Thanks! :)

Comment: Use `View Source` to see what elements are in the static HTML of the web page, before elements are added dynamically by JS.

Comment: @Barmar So if I'm right it should be `mat-app-background` or `app-loading` but none of them seems to work

Comment: You could just use `document.body`

Comment: The callback needs to check whether the class of the added element is `flip-card-back`

Comment: @Barmar Using `document.body` I'm able to print the `test3` but I'm not getting any kind of information in the call back. Could you show me an example? Thanks and sorry!

Comment: @Omar try these methods:
1) Put your js file importing in html file after `flip-card-back` element
2) Put your js file importing in html file in the bottom of `body`
3) Put your js file importing in html file in the bottom of `header` with `defer` attribute

Comment: I get the observer to work if I change this: `observer.observe(document.getElementsByClassName('results-content')[0], config);`

Comment: As an extension? Because it doesn't work for me neither in the extension nor the console. It says `TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[1] is undefined` I can get the result by using `'flip-card-back'` class in the console, but it doesn't work in the extension, `'results-content'` doesn't work either for me @Tawnos

Comment: I don't know what extension you're using. I just ran the code in the console and verified I could get the initial values as well as changes using css selectors and a MutationObserver.

Comment: Instead of using the console I'm using the JS code in firefox as an extension. (Just like extensions works in firefox/chrome, adding the js and its manifest)

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it, but I think you want something like this.

In the callback, loop through the added nodes and check for the class that you're looking for. If it's an attribute modification, check if the target element now has the class.

```js
document.getElementById("addcard").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let newNode = document.createElement("div");
  newNode.id = "card";
  document.getElementById("foo").appendChild(newNode);
});

document.getElementById("addclass").addEventListener("click", () => document.getElementById("card") ?.classList?.add("flip-card-back"));

console.log('test');
const targetNode = document.body;

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  attributes: true,
  attributeFilter: ['class']
};

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
  // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
  for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type = 'childList') {
      for (const node of mutation.addedNodes) {
        if (node?.classList?.includes("flip-card-back")) {
          alert("flip-card-back node added", node.innerHTML);
          return;
        }
      }
    } else if (mutation.type == 'attributes') {
      if (mutation.target.classList.includes("flip[-card-back")) {
        alert("flip-card-back class added", node.innerHTML);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
console.log('test2')
// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

```css
#foo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#card {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}

#card.flip-card-back {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>

<button id="addcard">Click to add node</button>
<button id="addclass">Click to add class</button>
```

Comment: After test it, the `flip-card-back added` console log never happened, the callback is called indeed, and the `test3` is printed too, but it seems it isn't still able to get the innerhtml (Sorry if I'm being a pain in the ass, I'm kinda new in js)

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: just `[POKER_LOGGER]:  – "setRoomObserver showEstimtates"` but I can confirm isn't something due to the extension but the page itself since I've tested it in others browsers without the extension.

Comment: It might be adding the class after adding the node, so I've added back the attribute check.

Comment: After trying to follow your example to implementing it in the extension I'm still not able to get any kind of response from the callback despite this one is finished successfully... :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use jQuery? if so, you could try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var eles = document.getElementsByClassName('flip-card-back')[0].innerHTML;
    console.log(eles);
})
```

Otherwise try this

```
(function() {
   var eles = document.getElementsByClassName('flip-card-back')[0].innerHTML;
    console.log(eles);
})();
```

Comment: I got the same problem, nothing is printed as @Barmar suggested it seems it's because the class isn't load yet when asking for it

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the actual window is loaded but **not the content inside of it**. It may take a little longer for the browser to setup all Elements depending on the Project. The Content is mostly rendered in the order you wrote it in HTML.
So i recommend putting the script **after the body tag**. Hope this explains and fixes your problem!